# Design approches in programming (OOP)

Tags: architecture

I want to study some approaches on realizing a project, designing an application, and so on. I'm not referring to Design Patterns as much as i'm referring at some design styles. For example MVC. So, in that order, I need some links, book names or other suggestions to study on this topic. If you have some thoughts, please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would start by reading upon Domain Driven Design. Eric Evans [Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) is a must-read on this topic. I can then recommend reading Jimmy Nilssons [Applying Domain Driven Design and Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321268202). This book has examples in .NET (C#) but you should be able to apply it to your language of choice.

[Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) by Steve McConnell is also a good read if you want to learn how to write clean, maintainable code.

If you like Head Firsts books, i can also recommend reading [Object-Oriented Analysis & Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008678).

For the record, MVC is a design pattern.

Comment: +1 for Domain Driven Design. If you want to know what all the fuzz is about before buying the book, check out http://thinkddd.com/. I would recommend buying the book though - it's a must have.